# Spring boot prometheus - difference between system_cpu_usage and process_cpu_usage

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot

Spring boot reports two statistics when Prometheus in place.

```
    # HELP system_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" for the whole system
    # TYPE system_cpu_usage gauge
    system_cpu_usage 0.029126213592233007
    
    # HELP process_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" for the Java Virtual Machine process
    # TYPE process_cpu_usage gauge
    process_cpu_usage 0.0
```

What is the difference between `system_cpu_usage`  and `process_cpu_usage`  ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand,

`system.cpu.usage` is host’s cumulative CPU usage in nanoseconds this includes user, system, idle CPU modes. (the sum of the /proc/stat CPU line)

`process.cpu.usage` is the cpu usage for the JVM process aka CPU time used by the JVM process

CPU usage aka CPU time is measured by counting the seconds that a CPU spends processing instructions from an application or from OS.

Both metrics are of type **Gauge** because their values that can go up or down as their showing a resource usage .